# Unable to send mail using JAMES mail server?

Tags: email, james

I have setup JAMES email server on my local windows system. Now I am trying to send mail to my yahoo account but I am getting the following error

```
13/11/10 12:39:56 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteAddrNotInNetwork: Authorized addresses: [127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255, 0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255, 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0] 
13/11/10 12:39:56 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: maxRetries is larger than total number of attempts specified. Increasing last delayTime with 19 attempts 
13/11/10 12:39:56 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Delay of 21600000 msecs is now attempted: 20 times 
13/11/10 12:40:04 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Attempting delivery of Mail1289631302656-0-to-yahoo.co.in to host mx1.mail.in.yahoo.com. at 180.222.96.138 for addresses [abhilash@yahoo.co.in] 
13/11/10 12:40:04 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Could not connect to SMTP host: 180.222.96.138, port: 25, response: 553 
13/11/10 12:40:04 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1289631302656-0-to-yahoo.co.in: 
13/11/10 12:40:04 INFO James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Storing message Mail1289631302656-0-to-yahoo.co.in into outgoing after 0 retries
```

As per the FAQs most probably I have some problem configuring my DNS server. So what I should set my DNS server to - my system's internal IP, my router's IP, my public IP. I'm confused. Any suggestions kindly share.

Answer (score 1):

In the startguide of JAMES it is said:

Determine the DNS server to use. On Windows, type ipconfig /all and look for the DNS servers. On Unix, look at /etc/resolv.conf. You will need this information in step #9.

https://wiki.apache.org/james/JamesQuickstart